# ggplot: Adding label with number of observations with number of different classes

Tags: r, ggplot2

How can I not only add a label with the number of observations (this is already nicely described here), but also the number of different classes, like for example:
**"*10 obervations* for *8 models* from *3 manufacturers*"** to each facet of the following plot?

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(y=cty)) + 
  geom_boxplot() +
  facet_grid(cols=vars(class))
```

[image: A simple plot created with ggplot2]

(The first three rows of the `mpg` dataset look like this:)

```
> head(mpg)
# A tibble: 6 × 11
  manufacturer model displ  year   cyl trans      drv     cty   hwy fl    class  
  <chr>        <chr> <dbl> <int> <int> <chr>      <chr> <int> <int> <chr> <chr>  
1 audi         a4      1.8  1999     4 auto(l5)   f        18    29 p     compact
2 audi         a4      1.8  1999     4 manual(m5) f        21    29 p     compact
3 audi         a4      2    2008     4 manual(m6) f        20    31 p     compact
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

# Calculate summary statistics for each facet
 mpg_summary <- mpg %>%
  group_by(class) %>%
  summarize(
    n_obs = n(),
    n_models = n_distinct(model),
    n_manufacturers = n_distinct(manufacturer)
  ) %>%
  mutate(
    label = paste0(
      n_obs,
      " observation",
      ifelse(n_obs != 1, "s", ""),  # Pluralize "observation" if more than 1
      " for ",
      n_models,
      " model",
      ifelse(n_models != 1, "s", ""),  # Pluralize "model" if more than 1
      " from ",
      n_manufacturers,
      " manufacturer",
      ifelse(n_manufacturers != 1, "s", "")  # Pluralize "manufacturer" if more than 1
    )
  )


# Create the plot with facets and labels
ggplot(mpg, aes(y = cty)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  facet_grid(cols = vars(class)) +
  geom_text(data = mpg_summary, aes(x = Inf, y = Inf, label = label), hjust = 1, vjust = 1, size = 3) +
  theme(strip.text.x = element_blank())  # Remove facet labels
```

Explanation
Group by "class" and compute observations, unique models, and manufacturers.
Create a label string combining these statistics.

Use ggplot with geom_boxplot and facet_grid on "class."

Utilize geom_text to display custom labels.
Position labels at the top-right corner, adjusting alignment and size.
Remove Redundant Labels by removing facet labels using theme(strip.text.x = element_blank()).

Comment: A more-varsity (but still rather literal) extension would be to not pluralize `model` and `manufacturer` if their respective values are 1. :-)

Comment: I edited is it correct @r2evans

Comment: Thanks for the solution and even caring about the details of grammar! This is what I was looking for not having been familiar with the possibility to give `geom_text()` a data frame.

Comment: U are welcome, and thanks to @r2evans , for guiding too